# Globbing pattern: exclude a directory

Tags: regex, shell, unix, find, glob

I have the following filepaths

```
/vol/form/various.txt
/vol/var/sender.py
/vol/var/hello.txt
```

I would like to get all `.txt` files that **do not** have the directory of `form` in them. For example, something like:

```
*.txt AND ! */form/*
```

What would be the correct globbing pattern to do this -- i.e, in a single pattern (or is that not possible)?

Comment: With a combination of `globstar` and `extglob`, this glob might work: `**/!(form)/*.txt` – but I've seen `!(...)` be not very reliable; for example, if there is a text file in a subdirectory of `form`, it won't be excluded, and `**/!(form)/**/*.txt` matches everything. But if the `.txt` file is always directly in the `form` directory, it should work.

Comment: Thoughed of this, but seems too fragile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
find /vol ! -path '*/form/*' -type f -name '*.txt'
```

If you need to negate a pattern, like with a *regex*, AFAIK *look around* are not supported by `find -regex*`. So it's not possible only with one `find` regex expression.

Comment: @Giles -- sure, is it possible to do it with just one `-path` argument? Or is the chaining necessary, that's basically my question.

Comment: You don't show us what you've tried, this is required for good quality question. Have you tested my solution ? It's a full working command. Dunno what you need more. It's exactly the purpose of your question

Comment: @david542 -- yes I know it works, I was just wondering about the ability to do more complex patterns in a single pattern string.

Comment: This is not in your original question. Don't change the rules in comments: open a new question if this is not not sufficient

Answer (score 1):

You can negate a grep:

```
find /vol -type f -name '*.txt' | grep -v '/form/'
```

If you want a *single regex* you need to either find file names with `find` and feed to GNU grep:

```
find /vol -type f | ggrep -oP "(?!.*?\/form\/)(^.*\.txt$)"
```

or use `Perl` with that same regex:

```
perl -MFile::Find -e 'find sub {
      print "$File::Find::name\n" if -f && m/(?!.*?\/form\/)(^.*\.txt$)/
      },"/vol/"'
```

Explanation of the regex:

```
(?!^.*?\/form\/)(^.*\.txt$)

^              ^                 Negative lookahead fail on /form/
                 ^       ^       Anchors for start and end of string
                   ^             all horizontal characters
                     ^^          literal . 
                                 (if not escaped it would match any character)
                       ^         txt extension
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/2jgJZf/5/)

Comment: Yes, but not in a _single expression_ or _single parrern_ like OP wrote

Comment: If you can do it in a single regex expression, show us =)

Comment: There you go! Possible but not elegant

Comment: Yes, not very obvious to re-use. What is `(^)` ? Don't get it

Comment: @GillesQuenot the `^` would mean start of the string (`$` would mean end). I don't think it's required here since the filepaths are sort of self-contained and anchored by themselves. Is that what you mean?

Comment: @GillesQuenot here's an example: https://regex101.com/r/V4ag0W/2. If you remove the `^` it could match starting from halfway into the filepath, rather than from the start of the line. Try removing the `^` in he above regex (I had to do that myself to see what it was needed, or if it was just cosmetic).

Comment: @dawg how about this for the regex? `^(?!.*?\/form\/).*\.txt` -- https://regex101.com/r/V4ag0W/3 ?

Comment: It doesn't match the second line: https://regex101.com/r/V4ag0W/4

Comment: @It's not supposed to, the extension there is `.py` instead of `.txt`.

Comment: yea I'm not sure, I don't know perl, but using those same inputs in regex101 it looks ok. I would ask @dawg why.

Comment: I am not sure what that pastebin is showing. Check the regex on regex101 and it works as stated....